# How to save an NSDictionary master key in an NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have a plist with the following structure:

```
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>000001</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Peter</string>
                    .
            .
        </dict>
        <key>000002</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Jack</string>
            .
                    .
        </dict>
            .
            .
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

I'm using this plist to create a table view, when the user selects a cell, I need to load another view with the data of the corresponding inner dictionary. I thought of a way to do this, but I need to be able to save the 000001 type keys, something like NSString *dictKey = [innerDict getMasterKey] or something, does such a thing exist?

EDIT: I forgot to mention I am building the plist from a json file on a server, so I can't modify the plist structure at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just pass the value along to the next view controller i.e. declare a property to store the key. I am pretty sure `getMasterKey` won't exist as the object can be include in many arrays and dictionaries at once so you can't backtrace unless you keep sort of indicator which in this case is best served by a property in the view controller.

Alternatively, you can consider [`associated objects`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject). You can look at this document for an [`example`](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html) and there are a few more on the net. However this would be overdoing it in my opinion unless you've a very specific purpose that using properties won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Stick a "MasterKey" / "00001" key/value pair in the dictionary....

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it won't work, because since I'm building the plist from a json file, I can't modify the plist structure.

Comment: If you are building the plist, the containment dictionary is likely mutable at some point?  You could also use associated objects.